# How to open new doc tab labels on the right side in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

When I open a new doc, its tab label appears on the left side of the bar. How can I make it appear on the right?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**To instruct Visual Studio that you want new tabs opened to the right of *existing* tabs:**

1. Click on the "Tools" menu, and select "Options".
2. Under the "Environment" heading in the listbox on the left, click on the "Documents" tab.
3. Check the box labeled "Insert documents to the right of existing tabs".

[image: Visual Studio document tab options]

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is that?

Comment: @NamG.VU On VS2012, it is under Tools - Options - Environment - Tabs and Windows - Tab Well

Comment: I'm on VS 2008 and do not see that checkbox on that options page.  Still hunting for it.

Comment: Don't think it is there in VS 2008, @richard. I believe it is a new feature in VS 2010, and continues to be available in later versions. You might try the [Tabs Studio extension](https://tabsstudio.com). (Or who knows, maybe in 2 years, you've upgraded!)

Comment: It's not there even in VS 2015 http://www.postimg.cz/images/2017/05/19/VS2015tabs.png

Comment: Look under the "Tabs and Windows" option, @youda008. It is the very first checkbox. I believe it is checked by default. Sorry I can't keep all of my old answers updated for each new version of the tools that are released.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017, the option is still under the "Tabs and Windows" option as @CodyGray stated in his previous comment. I believe the option is NOT checked b default.

Comment: For anyone looking for their code behind files to open immediately to the right of the tab instead of at the far right, this extension orders the tabs alphabetically. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell

Answer (score 149):

For **Visual Studio 2012 and later**, this setting has moved to the "Tabs and Windows" section.

Updated directions are:

1. Click on the "Tools" menu, and select "Options".
2. Under the "Environment" heading in the listbox on the left, click on the "Tabs and Windows" item.
3. Check the box labelled "Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs". This should be the first checkbox in the panel, in the "Tab Well" section.

Comment: I checked this box and tabs still open on the left (VS Ultimate 2013).

Comment: this works VS 2022

Answer (score 40):

In Visual Studio 2015, this option has been moved to Options --> Environment --> Tabs and Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2017 is the same like in Visual Studio 2015.
    Tools->Options->Environments->Tabs and Windows
You mus check "Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs"

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2019, this option is still under `Tools->Options->Environments->Tabs and Windows`, but it has been moved down. It is now placed under `Group tabs by project/path`:

[image]