# How to change the order of files when opening on VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, settings

The default is to open the file always on the left of the files already opened.

I would like to change the order when I open them the at the first time, to put the last opened files at the end.

Here is an example of the order when opening:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388110/how-to-open-new-doc-tab-labels-on-the-right-side-in-visual-studio

Comment: @SergeyVlasov thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows** and check the first checkbox "**Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs**"

The version of my VS is 2015.

[image]

When this option is checked the new tabs will open on the right

[image]

[image]